# need to convert the colname into float from string

Tags: python, pandas

```
for cond, grpby, aggcol, aggmethod, colname in zip(cond_arr, grpby_column, agg_column, agg_method, rename_column):
    rawdata.loc[cond, colname] = (rawdata.loc[cond, :].groupby(grpby)[aggcol].transform(aggmethod)).fillna(0.0)  
    rawdata[colname] = (rawdata.groupby(grpby)[colname].transform(aggreg_func_2))
```

i am using this code and getting next error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe and a desired output?

Comment: taskflow_cond = ((rawdata['Task Flow Type'].isin(['OrderInitiation', 'CaptureOrder'])) & 
                 (rawdata['_Excl_TaskDuration']=='N'))
cond_RevSub = (rawdata['Task Name']=='Review & Submit') & (rawdata['_Excl_TaskDuration']=='N')